# How to define dimension file for tvdpi tablet and tvdpi phone

Tags: android, xml, responsive-design

I am developing an android app with different value folders (values - mdpi, values - tvdpi, values - hdpi,..)

I have Samsung A (2016) 7" (1280x800) and Huawei Mediapad 2T 7" (1280x600)

I used an app called "What's my size" from play store to identify my device screen is belong to which values catagory (hdpi or mdpi or tvdpi or..)

I found, Samsung device is in - tvdpi caragory as tablet 
but Huawei device is in - tvdpi caragory as phone.

my problem is, when I run the app both devices accessing value from dimens(tvdpi) file.
but for Samsung device all dimens values fitting perfectly and for Huawei device dimens values looks too bigger.

Is there any other way to define values - tvdpi file to support different device screens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As taken from the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) `tvdpi` refers to:

> Resources for screens somewhere between mdpi and hdpi; approximately
>   213dpi. This is not considered a "primary" density group. It is mostly
>   intended for televisions and most apps shouldn't need it—providing
>   mdpi and hdpi resources is sufficient for most apps and the system
>   will scale them as appropriate. If you find it necessary to provide
>   tvdpi resources, you should size them at a factor of 1.33*mdpi. For
>   example, a 100px x 100px image for mdpi screens should be 133px x
>   133px for tvdpi.

So it might be better if you rather define `mdpi` and `hdpi` dimensions and the OS will size them accordingly. However, if you really need to define separate ones for `tvdpi`, you can try `xlarge-tvdpi` or `large-tvdpi` and just `tvdpi`.

Comment: earlier I did not have tvdpi and samsung took values from mdpi. but when I test a mdpi device (samsung tab 3 7") and tvdpi device (samsung tab A6 7") I saw a big different on UI. So, I created tvdpi layout. But yet I did not tried tvdpi - large. Thanks

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer if it solved your issue. :)

Comment: I changed your answer to ‘large-tvdpi’ and it worked fine. tvdpi-large showed me error. Thanks a lot for your answer. :)